# JMockit not matching recorded expectation

Tags: java, jmockit

I am attempting to mock the SAXParser.parse(...) methods using JMockit.

I am able to successfully setup Expectations for the parse(InputStream, DefaultHandler) method signature, but when I attempt to mock the parse(InputSource, DefaultHandler) signature, JMockit never sees the invocation and throws a MissingInvocation exception.

The following example shows two test cases, one mocking the InputSource flavor and one mocking the InputStream flavor:

```
public class SAXTest {

    @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
    public void testParseInputSource(@Mocked final SAXParser saxParser) throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            saxParser.parse((InputSource) any, (DefaultHandler) any); result = new RuntimeException("Fail now");
        }};

        SAXParser p = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        InputSource isource = new InputSource(new StringReader("<test/>"));
        p.parse(isource, new DefaultHandler());    
    }

    @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
    public void testParseInputStream(@Mocked final SAXParser saxParser) throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            saxParser.parse((InputStream) any, (DefaultHandler) any); result = new RuntimeException("Fail now");
        }};

        SAXParser p = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        InputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream("</test>".getBytes());
        p.parse(istream, new DefaultHandler());
    }
}
```

Running the testcase results in:

```
    JUnit version 4.12
E.
Time: 0.069
There was 1 failure:
1) testParseInputSource(SAXTest)
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.RuntimeException> but was<mockit.internal.MissingInvocation>
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
 ...
Caused by: Missing 1 invocation to:
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser#parse(any org.xml.sax.InputSource, any org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler)
   on mock instance: $Subclass_SAXParser_param0@490d6c15
Caused by: Missing invocations
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java)
        at SAXTest$1.<init>(SAXTest.java:20)
        at SAXTest.testParseInputSource(SAXTest.java:19)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 2,  Failures: 1
```

As you can see, the InputSource version fails, while the InputStream version works as expected.

I am using Junit 4.12 and JMockit 1.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the `@Capturing` annnotation instead of the `@Mocked` one on the `InputSource` test.

**Explanation**

Your problem is that `SAXParser.parse(InputSource, DefaultHandler)` method is overridden by `SAXParserImpl`. As you're using the `@Mocked` annotation, you are mocking only the methods from `SAXParser` class.

`SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()` returns a `SAXParserImpl`, so for the `InputStream` method, as there is no override, it goes to the mocked `SAXParser.parse(InputStream, DefaultHandler)` method.

BUT, for the `InputSource` method, as there is an override, it goes to the not mocked method, and hence the missing invocation.

If you were to use the `Capturing` annotation, that mocks an interface/class and all of its sub-classes/sub-implementations, you won't have the missing invocation exception.

Comment: Indeed. Except that up to JMockit 1.32, many internal JRE classes from non-standard packages (such as `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl`) are excluded from `@Capturing` due to past robustness issues. In JMockit 1.33, though, `com.sun.org` will be allowed. This said, IMO mocking an XML parser is unnecessary and best avoided.

Comment: I'm using 1.8 so didn't notice that :P